# Windows 8 developer tools from the ISO

Tags: windows-8-preview

I had to use the regular Windows 8 DP iso to make my OS install, because the ISO with developer tools was too big. I still have the ISO though. Any chance I could extract the tools from there and use them with my current "vanilla" Windows 8?

What I'm looking for are the SDK, VS11 and EB5. I really don't want to download them with my 1mbit connection if I potentially already have them.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.  It will depend on how the tools are stored on the DP ISO.  I haven't looked at the file structure, but you can use any number of utilities such as WinRar to browse and extract the files in the ISO.  If the developer tools were included with their own separate set of files or as a separate installer that the Dev Preview runs during installation, then you should be able to extract the files you need, transfer them to the install you created and install them there.  If they were merged in with all the other files, it's will make the task much more difficult.

Your only other option--that I am aware of--is that if you have an MSDN subscription, I hear you can download the VS11 preview there.  Don't have one myself, so I can't validate that.

I would recommend the approach I'm using instead.  Use a VM such as VirtualBox and install the Win8 Dev Preview with the toolset into a virtual machine on your normal machine.  Any VM will let you install the OS from an ISO file as well as from CD/DVD.

Answer (score 1):

The tools in the Win8x64withTools ISO come pre-installed in the OS, so I don't believe there is a way to extract them. Anyway, I recommend downloading the [Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=27543) since the VS11 in the Win8x64withTools ISO only has the express edition. Warning, it's a 8.7GB install.

If the bandwidth is really a problem, you're stuck with the ISO:

If your problem is the size of the installer ISO then you may be able to get around that using the [Windows AIK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343%28WS.10%29.aspx) (Automated Installation Kit) to create a VHD Win8 image. I have not done that with Windows 8 so I don't know if it works. I recommend against running in a virtual machine because depending on your machine and the VM software it can get really sluggish. Windows 8 uses a lot of hardware acceleration and that doesn't always happen in a VM. I am running Windows 8 native off a VHD and that does work with just minor HDD read/write slowdown.

You can 'burn' the Win8x64withTools ISO to a USB flash drive using the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) and that works great. One great walk through for using the USB tool with a VHD is by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx).

Hope that helps.

*Update: While the separate download of VS11 doesn't appear to be the express edition like in the Win8 ISO, I'm not sure that is is the full edition.*